# Does Ansible's systemd module a `daemon-reload` before starting a service?

Tags: ansible, systemd

I have a playbook where I first copy a new service file to /etc/systemd/system/ and then start the service. Normally, I'd have to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` before starting the service.

There is a `daemon_reload` parameter to the `systemd` module, but the description is not clear. It says "When set to `true`, runs daemon-reload even if the module does not start or stop anything." It sounds like it usually runs `daemon-reload` before starting or stopping services, and that this switch just makes it run `daemon-reload` always even when there's no state change.

Example of what I'm doing:

```yaml
- name: Install Foo
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Install SystemD service
      become: true
      copy:
        src: ./foo.service
        dest: /etc/systemd/system/
    - name: Ensure the service is running
      become: true
      systemd:
        name: mqtt-button.service
        enabled: true
        state: started
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansible does not implicitly run `systemctl daemon-reload`.

It only runs it when you set `daemon_reload: true`, but in this case it will run the `daemon-reload` command regardless of whether or not it needs to start or stop any services.

When in doubt about the documentation you can always refer to [the source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/44dcfde9b84177e7dfede11ab287789c577b82b5/lib/ansible/modules/systemd_service.py#L391).